# GRPC client in Java, need to pass metadata

Tags: java, metadata, grpc

When writing a GRPC client and submitting a request, I get the error "UNAUTHENTICATED: invalid credentails".
It is required to transfer 3 lines of metadata:

```
"clientid" = "1"
"workerid" = "2"
"instance" = "3"
```

Declare the metadata:

```
private Metadata.Key<String> clientid = Metadata.Key.of("clientid", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
private Metadata.Key<String> workerid = Metadata.Key.of("workerid", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
private Metadata.Key<String> instance = Metadata.Key.of("instance", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
```

Next, you need to transfer them to Credentials, but it doesn't work. Tried to implement through mock stubs, but also an error:

```
public class MethodAdd {
   private CallCredentials callCredentials;
   @Mock
   private Executor mockExecutor = Mockito.mock(Executor.class);
   @Mock
   private RequestInfo mockRequestInfo = Mockito.mock(RequestInfo.class);
   public MetadataApplier metadataApplier;
   private Metadata.Key<String> clientid = Metadata.Key.of("clientid", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
   private Metadata.Key<String> workerid = Metadata.Key.of("workerid", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
   private Metadata.Key<String> instance = Metadata.Key.of("instance", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

public void add(String target, int instanceId) throws InterruptedException {
   ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(target)
                .usePlaintext()
                .build();
   BlockingStub stub = newBlockingStub(channel);
   Metadata headers = new Metadata();
        headers.put(clientid, "1");
        headers.put(workerid, "2");
        headers.put(instance, Integer.toString(instanceId));
   metadataApplier.apply(headers);
   callCredentials.applyRequestMetadata(mockRequestInfo, mockExecutor, metadataApplier);
   stub.withCallCredentials(callCredentials).add(Empty.newBuilder().build());
   channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}
```

Can you please tell me if I need to override some methods? Or is there an even easier option? Need help!

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I managed to make a working method.
I created a separate class to get an authorization token and then used it as Credentials:

```
package grpc;
import io.grpc.CallCredentials;
import io.grpc.Metadata;
import io.grpc.Status;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
    
public class ApplyMetadata extends CallCredentials {
    private String clientid;
    private String workerid;
    private String instance;
    private Metadata.Key<String> c = Metadata.Key.of("clientid", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
    private Metadata.Key<String> w = Metadata.Key.of("workerid", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);
    private Metadata.Key<String> i = Metadata.Key.of("instance", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER);

    public ApplyMetadata(String clientid, String workerid, String instance) {
        this.clientid = clientid;
        this.workerid = workerid;
        this.instance = instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyRequestMetadata(RequestInfo requestInfo, Executor executor, MetadataApplier metadataApplier) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Metadata headers = new Metadata();
                headers.put(c, clientid);
                headers.put(w, workerid);
                headers.put(i, instance);
                metadataApplier.apply(headers);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                metadataApplier.fail(Status.UNAUTHENTICATED.withCause(e));
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void thisUsesUnstableApi() {
        // noop
    }
}
```

In my method it just:

```
ApplyMetadata token = new ApplyMetadata(clientId, workerId, Integer.toString(instanceId));
stub.withCallCredentials(token).add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

io.grpc.CallCredentials is an abstract class, it would be up to the implementation to provide applyRequestMetadata().  If you have something that extends CallCredentials and it uses the executor, having a mock instead of a real executor may skip doing the expected task.